# Accessing a attribute of another object through a model linked by ManyToMany

Tags: django, templates, many-to-many, models

Here are my two models

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        description = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        def __unicode__(self, ):
            return self.name

    class Post(models.Model):
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

        def __unicode__(self, ):
           return self.subject
```

I'm displaying the subject, description, and date of each post in a template.  But I also want to display the respective category for each post as well.

Here's the part of my view

```
def index(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by("-created")
    return render(request,'posts/index.html', {'posts':posts})
```

and then how I'm trying to display it in a template:

```
    {% for post in posts %}
        <div>
           {{ post.subject }}<br />
            {{ post.description }}<br />
            {{ post.created }} | of {{ post.category }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

But the category will not show up, all I get is

```
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x7ff7e40a0c90>
```

I've tried doing post.category.name and other random combinations but it either gives nothing or a parsing error.  I have no idea how to get the category displayed.

Answer (score 0):

That's a `Manager`. Use it as you would any other `Manager` (e.g. `Post.objects`).

```
{% for category in post.category.all %}
```

Comment: How could I get the category that's been picked with the post?

Comment: "Category"? It's a `ManyToManyField`; there could be *multiple* categories.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding this right. But how I have it set up right now, I can go in admin and make new posts, but for each one it requires me to select one of the category objects.  Is there a way for me to access the specific category for each post?

Comment: `ManyToManyField` creates a [**many-to-many relation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29). There isn't a "specific category" for each post.